# How to mount my SYNOLOGY NAS Diskstation DS214se on Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: nas

I'm a beginner on the Linux-Ubuntu community.

Problem: failed to mount a network drive and keep getting message: "mount.cifs permission denied".

I have tried the suggestions as posted article:
[mount.cifs permission denied](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735391/mount-cifs-permission-denied?newreg=d9115fc292b14d269ed343446544c5d8)

Can someone please let me know what else can I do?
Can I simply use a USB cable (instead of the network Ethernet cable) to access my SYNOLOGY NAS directly ? If so how to do that ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Synology and Ubuntu are Linux so use native protocols, keyword: NFS

Comment: Native protocols ? Does this mean we don't have to do anything ?
I managed to create a folder (called A-SYN-DS214se) under my Network main folder:
Then when I click on this A-SYN-DS214se folder I keep getting the annoying message:
"An error occurred while accessing 'Home', the system responded: mount.cifs: permission denied".
Can you please answer more specifically ?

Comment: Create in NAS NFS share. Then mount this share in Linux.